# Angular2+ Replace Text

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm new to Angular and trying to lean something ;)

How could I Replace a Specific text with another one ?

for instance:

I'l fetch data from a loki db by models ,
My component html looks like:

```
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let -1="rowData" let-user let-index="rowIndex">
  <tr [pSelectableRow]="user">
    <td>{{user.id}}</td>
    <td>{{user.userName}}</td>
    <td>{{user.name}}</td>
    <td>{{user.role}}</td>
    <td>{{user.active ? 'aktiv' : 'inaktiv'}}</td>
  </tr>
</ng-template>
```

where user.role is an output's users Role

-> these are the values iam writing to the database..

super_admin
admin
employee

I want to replace the text

super_admin with Super Admin or something else.
Could I achieve that with Pipes ? And how ?

Thx so far ;)

Comment: you want to replace the text only in front end?

Comment: Only the frontend view yes..

Comment: you want to change the super_admin to Super Admin you can achive this by using pipe

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7b1eWgSHiM1QV6vDUAB0?p=preview

Comment: It is the most basic try to do on your own otherwise you will lack to learn.Follow the shared url

Comment: @ChellappanV could u provide a Example ? ;) thy !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make an enum with the values to display

```
export enum Roles {
    super_admin = ‘Super Admin’;
    admin = ‘Admin’;
    user = ‘Standard Nerd’;
}
```

And add it to your component

```
public Roles = Roles;
```

Then in your template

```
{{Roles[user.role]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a pipe for that.

```
<td>{{user.role | roleToStr}}</td>
```

Your pipe will look like this :

```js
transform(role: string) {
  return role
    .split('_')
    .map(word => word = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
    .join(' ')
}
```

Here is a snippet to show the result :

```js
const role = 'super_admin';

const str = role
  .split('_')
  .map(word => word = word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + word.slice(1).toLowerCase())
  .join(' ');
  
console.log(str);
```

Comment: this worked for me too. But i used the Enum instead ! thx for your Solution !

Comment: The enum forces you to implement your business logic both on backend and front-end. If you're aware you're going to do the same work twice and still want that solution, then great !

Comment: i know that the pipe seams to be the better "option" But i need it only 1 time on the Front View.. so the Enum is less code for it ;) but however.. Thx for your Solution !